Object recognition and barcode scanning with the same camera
I'm working in a computer vision project applied to manufacturing where the clients wants to perform object recognition and counting using computer vision. Additionally part of the process requires that the operator scans a barcode in a document and the client asked if we can use the same camera. My first intuition was to say no, because I haven't seen an implementation like that and the processes of object recognition and barcode scanning are very different.
However, I don't see a technical reason why it wouldn't be possible so I'd like to find someone that has worked on something like that to help me answer the following questions:

Is it possible?
Is it convenient?
What are the trade offs to decide whether two separate systems must be implemented vs a multipurpose system?


For barcode scanning and object recognition in a manufacturing setting, the key challenge is optimizing optical parameters across both tasks. Let $W$ be the number of modules in a barcode and $M$ the minimum pixel requirement per module.
The point spread function (PSF) radius at depth $z$ with focal length $f$ and effective aperture $D$ under illumination wavelength $\lambda$ is:
$$
r(z) \approx \frac{1.22\,\lambda\,f}{D}\,\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{z - s}{s}\right)^2}
$$
where $s$ represents the focal distance. The effective resolution $R_{\text{eff}}(z)$ comes from convolving the PSF with nominal sensor resolution $R_0$:
$$
R_{\text{eff}}(z) = R_{0} \,\otimes\, \text{PSF}\bigl(r(z)\bigr)
$$
With noise factor $\gamma$, barcode decoding requires:
$$
M \;\ge\; \bigl\lceil \gamma\,W \bigr\rceil
$$
For object recognition, given object bounding box size $A$ and required pixel count $\alpha$, with camera factor $\beta$:
$$
A\,\beta \;\ge\; \alpha
$$
These requirements must be satisfied across all relevant depths:
$$
\min_{z \,\in\,[z_{\text{barcode}},\,z_{\text{object}}]} R_{\text{eff}}(z)\;\;\ge\;\;\max\!\Bigl\{\,\lceil \gamma\,W \rceil,\;\,\frac{\alpha}{A\,\beta}\Bigr\}
$$
The depth of field boundaries for focal length $f$, aperture $N$, and focus distance $s$ are:
$$
d_{\text{near}} \approx \frac{s\;\bigl(f^2 - N\,c\,(s - f)\bigr)}{\,f^2 + N\,c\,(s - f)\,},
\quad
d_{\text{far}} \approx \frac{s\;\bigl(f^2 + N\,c\,(s - f)\bigr)}{\,f^2 - N\,c\,(s - f)\,}
$$
where $c$ represents the maximum acceptable circle of confusion.
The system cost can be evaluated through:
$$
\mathcal{C} \;=\; c_{\text{hardware}} \;+\; c_{\text{calibration}}
\;+\; \epsilon_{\text{performance}}
\;+\; \int_{0}^{T}\!\bigl(1 - \eta(t)\bigr)\,dt
$$
Here's an implementation incorporating these principles:
import cv2
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import numpy as np
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class OpticalParameters:
    focal_length: float    # mm
    aperture_number: float # f-number
    wavelength: float      # nm
    sensor_width: float    # mm
    pixel_size: float      # μm

class VisionSystem:
    def __init__(self, optical_params: OpticalParameters):
        self.optical_params = optical_params
        self.net = self._initialize_yolo()
        self.classes = self._load_classes()
        
    def _initialize_yolo(self):
        net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolov3.cfg', 'yolov3.weights')
        net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
        net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)
        return net
        
    def _load_classes(self):
        with open('yolov3.txt', 'r') as f:
            return [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    
    def calculate_psf_radius(self, z, s):
        wavelength_mm = self.optical_params.wavelength / 1e6
        f = self.optical_params.focal_length
        D = f / self.optical_params.aperture_number
        return 1.22 * wavelength_mm * f / D * np.sqrt(1 + ((z - s)/s)**2)
    
    def calculate_depth_of_field(self, s, c):
        f = self.optical_params.focal_length
        N = self.optical_params.aperture_number
        
        d_near = s * (f**2 - N*c*(s - f)) / (f**2 + N*c*(s - f))
        d_far = s * (f**2 + N*c*(s - f)) / (f**2 - N*c*(s - f))
        
        return d_near, d_far
    
    def detect_objects(self, frame, conf_threshold=0.5, nms_threshold=0.4):
        height, width = frame.shape[:2]
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1/255.0, (416, 416),
                                    swapRB=True, crop=False)
        self.net.setInput(blob)
        layer_names = self.net.getLayerNames()
        output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in 
                        self.net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
        layer_outputs = self.net.forward(output_layers)

        boxes, confidences, class_ids = [], [], []
        for output in layer_outputs:
            for detection in output:
                scores = detection[5:]
                class_id = np.argmax(scores)
                confidence = scores[class_id]
                if confidence > conf_threshold:
                    center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                    center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                    w = int(detection[2] * width)
                    h = int(detection[3] * height)
                    x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                    y = int(center_y - h / 2)
                    boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                    confidences.append(float(confidence))
                    class_ids.append(class_id)
                    
        indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, conf_threshold, 
                                  nms_threshold)
        detections = []
        if len(indices) > 0:
            for i in indices.flatten():
                x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
                label = str(self.classes[class_ids[i]])
                conf = confidences[i]
                detections.append((x, y, w, h, label, conf))
        return detections

    def decode_barcodes(self, frame):
        barcodes = decode(frame)
        results = []
        for barcode in barcodes:
            barcode_data = barcode.data.decode('utf-8')
            (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
            results.append((barcode_data, x, y, w, h))
        return results

    def process_frame(self, frame):
        barcode_results = self.decode_barcodes(frame)
        object_detections = self.detect_objects(frame)
        
        for (bdata, bx, by, bw, bh) in barcode_results:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (bx, by), (bx+bw, by+bh), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, bdata, (bx, by - 10),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                       
        for (x, y, w, h, label, conf) in object_detections:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, f"{label} {conf:.2f}", (x, y - 10),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255, 0, 0), 2)
                       
        return frame, len(barcode_results), len(object_detections)

def main():
    optical_params = OpticalParameters(
        focal_length=12.0,    # 12mm lens
        aperture_number=2.8,  # f/2.8
        wavelength=550,       # green light
        sensor_width=6.17,    # typical 1/2.3" sensor
        pixel_size=2.0        # 2.0μm pixels
    )
    
    vision_system = VisionSystem(optical_params)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
            
        processed_frame, num_barcodes, num_objects = vision_system.process_frame(frame)
        cv2.putText(processed_frame,
                    f"Barcodes: {num_barcodes}, Objects: {num_objects}",
                    (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        
        cv2.imshow("Multipurpose Vision System", processed_frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
            break
            
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

A single camera can handle both tasks if performance penalties remain low compared to hardware savings. However, specialized scenarios may benefit from separate cameras optimized for each task. The choice depends on balancing hardware costs, calibration needs, and performance requirements while maintaining adequate resolution across working distances.
The temporal efficiency term in the cost function ($\int_{0}^{T}\!\bigl(1 - \eta(t)\bigr)\,dt$) helps quantify throughput losses from any compromises in the unified system, which should be weighed against the hardware and maintenance benefits of using a single camera.

Great analysis. Welcome to our community.
